# Spinors and Gamma matrices

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices

Do gamma matrices and Dirac spinors commute? I mean, if I have the expression $$\gamma_{\mu} \psi,$$ can i say that it´s equal to $$\psi \gamma_{\mu}~?$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do $\gamma$ matrices commute with the Dirac spinor field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414440/)